# difference between v4l2_ioctl and ioctl

Tags: linux, ioctl, v4l2

I am currently investigating how we can use v4l2 devices from python, and found that python has a binding for ioctl (https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html).

I done some implemntations in C, but i have a hard time understanding if ioctl is the same as v4l2_ioctl?

They seem to take the exact same arguments, in the official examples i see both wrapped in a function, that is used in the same way:

```
static void xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
{
        int r;

        do {
                r = v4l2_ioctl(fh, request, arg);
        } while (r == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));

        if (r == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
```

And for the normal ioctl:

```
static int xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
{
        int r;

        do {
                r = ioctl(fh, request, arg);
        } while (-1 == r && EINTR == errno);

        return r;
}
```

I looked in the linux repository, but could not figure out the exact difference between the two.

Can i use ioctl and v4l2_ioctl interchangeably?
If so why does both exist?
If not, what is the limitations of ioctl compared to v4l2_ioctl?

Comment: `in the official examples i see both wrapped in a function,` which examples?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link the examples:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/v4l2grab.c.html
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use ioctl and v4l2_ioctl interchangeably?

No.

> If so why does both exist?

`ioctl` exists to do some special operations on devices.

`v4l2_ioctl` is a wrapper from `libv4l2` to simplify operations on v4l2 devices.

From [README](https://github.com/philips/libv4l/blob/master/README):

> ### libv4l2
>
> This offers functions like v4l2_open, v4l2_ioctl, etc. which can by
> used to quickly make v4l2 applications work with v4l2 devices with
> weird formats. libv4l2 mostly passes calls directly through to the
> v4l2 driver. When the app does a TRY_FMT / S_FMT with a not supported
> format libv4l2 will get in the middle and emulate the format (if an
> app wants to know which formats the hardware can *really* do it should
> use ENUM_FMT, not randomly try a bunch of S_FMT's). For more details
> on the v4l2_ functions see libv4l2.h .

And [the source found in libv4l project](https://github.com/philips/libv4l/blob/cdfd2992de72b93e588e0126491f17c30b9e6f43/libv4l2/libv4l2.c#L744) is the ultimate code documentation.

Comment: A small follow up question for you.
If v4l2_ioctl is a wrapper, does that mean i can potentially do the same things with ioctl, though it may be harder/more time consuming? or will i be limited if i go with ioctl?

Comment: also, i stumbled on the project you link to myself, but i also found this definition (which is different, and seems to call itself recursively) https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-dev.c#L358
this one also defines v4l2_ioctl

Comment: `If v4l2_ioctl is a wrapper, does that mean i can potentially do the same things with ioctl, though it may be harder/more time consuming?` Se v4l2_ioctl sources for things it needs.. I do not see nothing special there, with a single `SYS_IOCTL` call near the end.  `his one also defines v4l2_ioctl` This is a kernel v4l2 driver function that handles v4l2 ioctl.